# Why does air flow over and bottom surfaces of a wing

Tags: aerodynamics

A very basic question....Why does air flow over and bottom surfaces of a wing? The wing is moving relative to stationary air.when the wing leading edge hits the air molecule, air molecule should move forward, not over n below the wing.....but why? It is really bothering me....pls help me

Comment: I am sorry, but this question doesn't even begin to make any sense. Why in all the world would you expect anything different, and if you do, what in all the world would that be? Have you ever run your hand, say, through water? What do you think happened? The flow of the water around your hand in this case is completely analogous to the flow of air around an airfoil.

Comment: Just wanted to know why it happens? Just wanted to know what's wrong in my thinking....

Comment: *[Unnecessarily confrontational remark removed - ACM]* You can also consider one of those popular ball pools that they have at kindergartens and play places, and try to imagine what happens when you move an object through those balls. What do you think those balls will do?

Comment: Have you ever pushed a knife through cheese or butter? Does the cheese or butter get pushed forward in front of the knife, or does it split and go along the sides? Even if the knife is really dull, what happens?

Comment: I just want to know why it happens?what is the reason??

Answer (score 2):

Usually when we consider flow around an object, we make that object stationary so we can see the "flow" more clearly. In the case of a wing, because of drag the air is probably moving in the same direction as the plane - just much more slowly. In the frame of reference of the plane, that makes the air move from front to back.

In fact, in a confined space you can show that as an object moves one way through the liquid, that liquid must be moving the other way (to fill the space left by the object). You can see this very nicely if you take a transparent plastic bottle that's almost full of a viscous liquid (shampoo, dish detergent); give it a shake to generate lots of small bubbles. Then tip the bottle upside down so the large bubble at the top will flow (back) to the surface. As the big bubble goes up, you will see little bubbles in the liquid *going down* (because they are being entrained by the liquid flowing around the bubble).

Comment: I just want to know why it happens?

Comment: Wing pushes air. Pressure in front of wing increases, and pressure behind it decreases (where there was wing, now there is void). Air flows to compensate for the difference in pressure.